# calculating duplicates payload from text file Python

Tags: python, dictionary, readfile

I am trying to calculate the scores entry for people from a text file:

essi 5
pietari 9
essi 2
pietari 10
pietari 7
aps 25
essi 1

output expected:

Contestant score:
aps 25
essi 8
pietari 26

my output:
aps 25
essi 11
pietari 77

my code calculation is wrong!

my code is:

```
def reading():
"""
reads input file name and open it, split lines from text in 2.
do the calculation, print out the dictionary
:return: dict.
"""
file1 = input("Enter the name of the score file: ")
read_file = open(file1, mode="r")
dict = {}

for line in read_file:
    # Remove the character(s) that end the line.
    line = line.rstrip()

    # Split the line in two.
    name, score = line.split(" ")

    # Add a new entry to the phone book.
    if name not in dict:
        dict[name] = score

    elif name in dict:
        dict[name] = score + score

#Close the file.
read_file.close()

#print dict sorted
for p in sorted(dict.keys()):
    print(f"{p} {dict[p]}")

def main():
    #the function call
    reading()

if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Comment: What is the problem then?

Comment: Sorry I edited the question, my code not calculating correctly, my output results number is  wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below. (`zz.txt` holds your data)

Few points that you need to take from the code:
@ do not name you data structure variable 'dict'
@ use 'with' when you open files
@ work with defaultdict when you can

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(int)
with open('zz.txt') as f:
    lines = [l.strip() for l in f.readlines()]
    for line in lines:
        fields = line.split(' ')
        data[fields[0]] += int(fields[1])
print(data)
```

output

```
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'essi': 8, 'pietari': 26, 'aps': 25})
```

Comment: @Alsakka Great. It is important that you will try and understand the code and try and use the concepts in your future code.

Comment: exactly, to be honest your code is quite advanced for my current knowledge but m doin my best to analyze it!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is when you split here

```
# Split the line in two.
name, score = line.split(" ")
```

You get two strings which gives an unexpected behavior when you add them in line

```
dict[name] = score + score
```

What you can do is cast the score string to and integer. Add this line and it will fix your problem

```
    # Split the line in two.
    name, score = line.split(" ")
    score = int(score)
```

Also change your line for updating your dict to this

```
dict[name] += score
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for analyzing, I needed that to understand where is the issue actually!